# character that represents new line across all platforms in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

**specs**

I am working on Linux Mint 14. I started on JavaScript recently and I tried to do some output formatting(printing random numbers, one per line) and as usual used `\n`. But this does not seem to work.

On both the chromium web browser and mozilla firefox, only a space shows up.

**code**

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>

<TITLE> GENERATE RANDOM NUMBERS AND PRINT THEM </TITLE>

<BODY>

<div id='container'>

<button onclick='startPrinting()'>Generate random numbers </button>

</div>

</BODY>

</HTML>

</HEAD>

<script>

function startPrinting()
{

var b = document.getElementById('container');

//b.innerHTML += Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);

b.innerHTML += '<br>The following are some random numbers.<br>';

for(var i =1;i<10;i++)
{

b.innerHTML += '\n';

b.innerHTML += i + '.' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);

}

}

</script>
```

I tried `<br>` and this worked well. But now I have many files where I have `\n`.

So is there a way that I can tell the script to replace all occurences of `\n` with `<br>`?

If possible please give an answer that will ensure that i have to add only a few lines of code to my existing files.

(I am looking for something like `#define` in C++)

**please** help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Your issue is not that `'\n'` isn't a newline, it's that when *rendering HTML* all whitespace is treated the same (as spaces).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it inside a `pre` tag, which expects pre-formatted text and will treat `\n` as a newline:

```
<pre id="container">
    1
    2
    3
<pre>
```

Will ouput:

```
1
2
3
```

You can try this out here on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zULEB/1/)

Comment: well I don't have pre-formatted text.... Can you help me with the JS output that I have?

Comment: @IcyFlame: well just change the `div` to `pre` and use `\n` as newline.

Comment: @IcyFlame: Why can't you just surround your generated text with `<pre>` ... `</pre>` tags?

Comment: @IcyFlame: Check out the JsFiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/zULEB/1/. Why the downvote btw?

Answer (score 0):

IF I have understood the question correctly, you need a list of numbers, vertically ?

If so then Its as simple as below.

```
function startPrinting()
    {

    var b = document.getElementById('container');

    var nums =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] 

    var html =[]
    html.push("<ul>")
    for(var i =1;i<nums .length;i++)
    {

    html.push("<li>"+nums[i] +"</li>"); 

    }
    html.push("</ul>")
    b.innerHTML =html.join("");
    }
```